# Find html markup tags by their id wicket

Tags: java, html, wicket

I have this table column which sometimes needs to be hidden..

```
<td id="row1"><span wicket:id="state">Servicio de Reprografia</span></td>
```

Is it possible for me to find this somehow through java code and add a hidden attribute in order to completely hide this markup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use `<wicket:enclosure>` to hide the surrounding markup when the wicket component is hidden:

```
<wicket:enclosure>
    <td id="row1"><span wicket:id="state">Servicio de Reprografia</span></td>
</wicket:enclosure>


state.setVisible(false);
target.addComponent(state);
```

Comment: Wow, this comes in handy. Didn't know about `<wicket:enclosure>` before. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: +1 When setting visibility through Ajax, remember to use [`Component#setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(boolean)`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(boolean))

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to do this in an `onClick()` or `onSubmit()` handler of one of your components on the page. In this case, you have to call:

```
getPage().get("path:to:component").setVisibleAllowed(false);
```

Furthermore, if you do this within an AJAX callback, you have to add the (now hidden) component to the `AjaxRequestTarget`.

`path.to.component` corresponds to the nesting of your wicket components. This will allow you to hide the `<span>` element. If you want to hide the `<td>`, too, I'd advise to move your `wicket:id` tag to the `<td>`element.

Comment: It is better to override the `isVisible` method of the component rather then setting it with `setVisible` which is sometimes unreliable.

Comment: Not, it's not. `isVisible` is likely to be called very often per request and overriding it can lead to serious side effects. I've looked into the matter and found out that using `isVisibleAllowed` and `setVisibleAllowed` is the preferred way to control visibility because they are final and thus cannot be overridden. I'll change my answer to reflect what I've found out.

Comment: The path separator is `:` and not `.`. Use `setVisibleAllowed()` only in your security framework. The preferred way to define component visibility is to override `onConfigure()` and use `setVisible()` there - it's only executed once.